# How can I replace constants 5,6 & 8 in sql instead of in condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

In the following query, I would like to make the values in the `IN` dynamic.

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
INTO #tmp_new_part
FROM #party_approval
WHERE party_approval_type_id in (5,6,8)
```

Comment: Have a subquery look for `party_approval_type_id` in another table.

Comment: As you are on SQL Server 2008 the preferred way would probably be to pass these values in via a [table valued parameter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the values you want to go in the IN list are from an existing table or from a SQL parameter. If they are from an existing table or query you can do something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
INTO #tmp_new_part
FROM #party_approval
WHERE party_approval_type_id in (select party_approval_type_id from some_table)
```

If you want it to be based on parameters to a stored procedure, you can pass a varchar containing a delimited list of values, and use one of the many existing UDFs to split it into a table variable, similar to below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT party_id 
INTO #tmp_new_part
FROM #party_approval
WHERE party_approval_type_id in (select * from dbo.CsvToInt(@values))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a XML document as a parameter. This is a trick used when one needs to pass an array of distinct values to a stored procedure. [An example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069388/503046) from Stack Overflow is nice an illustration about the technique:

```
declare @xmlDoc XML
set @xmlDoc = '
<ids>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>2</id>
</ids>'

declare @handle int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle output, @XMLDoc

select * from MyTable where id in (
    select id from openxml( @handle, '/ids/id') with (id int '.')
)
```